# Allocating generic class in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a Testbench that can test different implementations of an Interface. Coming from Java I would love to just specify an Interface, create some Classes that implement it and write a `class Testbench<T extends MyInterface>`

Transforming this approach to C++ gives something like:

```
// The Interface
class Animal {
public:
    Animal(int age) {};

    virtual ~Animal() {};
    virtual void Say();
};

// An Implementor
class Cow : Animal {
private:
    int age;

public:
    Cow(int age) : Animal(age) {
        this.age = age;
    };
    void Say() {
        std::cout << "I'm an " << age << " year old Cow" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Next I define the templated class that can test different Animals:

```
template<> void AnimalTestbench<class T> {
   static void TestSay();
}
```

But when I try to implement the TestSay method, it gives me "Allocation of incomplete type T"

```
template<> void AnimalTestbench<class T>::TestSay() {
    T *animal = new T(5);
    animal->Say();
}
```

Of course I didn't specify that T should be an Animal, this is my first question. The latter is: why does this code fail?

I've heard that Templates are a fancy way for Macros that know about types, but if it's a Macro in a way, then the compiler should first replace T with my (complete) Type which he should be able to allocate and instantiate.

Comment: 1) `template<> void AnimalTestbench<class T>` huh? Didn't you mean `template<class T> void AnimalTestbench`? Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). 2) In addition: `this.age = age;` doesn't compile as well. It should be, at the very least, `this->age = age;` (or you could use constructor initializer list to initialize members).

Comment: Also, you don't need templates.  If you have a concrete interface, you can use a pointer to the base class.  And the base class should be abstract if it's not intended to be an instance on its own.  And the age should be in the base class as well (probably).  As @AlgirdasPreidžius said, you need a good C++ book.  You're translating Java concepts in a "not quite right" way to C++.

Comment: A C++ book seems like a good suggestion. That `new T` leaks.

Comment: Be sure to implement it in the header file or to explicitly define it in the header. Also `TestSay` leaks `animal`.

Comment: I want to use templates because the tests should invoke the constructors of their targeted classes. Or could I also do that with pointers?

The memory leak was just to keep the example small but you're right I should definitely deconstruct the animal after the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

- The `Animal` class should declare `Say` as pure virtual
- The `Animal` class uses `this.` instead of `this->`
- The `Cow` class does not derive publicly from `Animal`
- The `AnimalTestbench` class does not use templates correctly, `template<>` defines a specialization, which is not what you want
- `T *animal = new T(5);` is a memory leak, because a `delete` doesn't follow.

  - we don't need to allocate at all, actually

Fixed `Animal` class:

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal(int) {};

    virtual ~Animal() {};
    virtual void Say() = 0;
};
```

Fixed `Cow` class:

```
class Cow : public Animal {
private:
    int age;

public:
    Cow(int age) : Animal(age) {
        this->age = age;
    };
    void Say() override{
        std::cout << "I'm an " << age << " year old Cow" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Fixed `AnimalTestbench` (we don't need to separate the impl of `TestSay` from the declaration, but I'm following your approach:

```
template<class T>
struct AnimalTestbench
{
   static void TestSay();
};

template<class T>
void AnimalTestbench<T>::TestSay() {
    T animal(5);
    Animal *animal_base = &animal;
    animal_base->Say();
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    AnimalTestbench<Cow>::TestSay();
}
```

`TestSay` could be a standalone templated function, but I presume there are other virtual functions you wish to test and it's convenient to put them all in a single test class.

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p9uvPyLKg4Hph8Ys)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for template classes is:

```
template<typename T> void AnimalTestbench {
   static void TestSay();
}
```

And the method:

```
template<typename T> void AnimalTestbench<T>::TestSay() {
    T *animal = new T(5);
    animal->Say();
}
```

Comment: That first `<T>` shouldn't be there; it's no specialization.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters, I fixed it.